# Stretch="uniform" not behaving as expected on Silverlight MediaElement

Tags: c#, silverlight, mediaelement

I am using the following XAML to display streaming video through a Silverlight media element:

```
<UserControl x:Class="slplayer.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  Padding="0">
        <!-- source is set to a custom MediaStreamSource in code behind -->
        <MediaElement Name="mediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Stretch="Uniform" />
</UserControl>
```

And expect that video should playback and should, depending on the size of the playback window, consume either all available horizontal space or all available vertical space and scale the non-constrained dimension to maintain the aspect ratio of the video.

In the case where the vertical dimension is constrained this is exactly what happens, however (as you can see in the screen shot below) when the horizontal dimension is constrained a significant amount of space is left on either side and the vertical dimension is scaled to this narrower width.

My question is why is the video not consuming all horizontal space?

Things I've tried:

- simplifying the layout (which is how I got the above XAML)
- hosting the control in both a web browser and a SilverlightViewportElement
- modifying the dimensions of the mp4 file and video track
- playing the mp4 file in WMP (which scales correctly)
- setting css styles on the html, body, div, and object used

The problem illustrated:

[image: The problem illustrated]

Comment: After a hundred of tests, I can't to reproduce the same problem. If you are not using styles or control templates in your application and if the video is right as you said, the problem is your html/css. Please, post more usefull information about it.

Comment: Why are you not using `UniformToFill`. Also, could you provide the CSS from your view-source? Default or Other CSS could be affecting your page.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata UniformToFill clip the video instead of stretching it to fill the smaller dimension.  Keep in mind that slviewport uses COM interop so here is no CSS.  That said I ultimatly got it to work by using an embeded web browser control and replacing individual styling with a * {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100% } though I still don't fully understand why this worked since it should have been identical to the previous css that had it set on each element.

Comment: I think you was not setting margin and padding to HTML tags and BODY. This is usually the margins problem. With * you are applying the style over all tags, including HTML and BODY. I hope this helps you to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `MediaElement` in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Put your MediaElement in a Grid and remove all Alignment Stretch settings and also Padding and Margin too. Only set Stretch as uniform for MediaElement.

PS: Check your aspx div for Silverlight object. Its Width and Height might have been set with wrong values.